# Condition in Ant not working properly

Tags: jenkins, ant

I'm doing a task in Ant which tests whether a server is stopped or running, and in case the server is stoppped, the Ant task fail and sends an email. The problem is that my condition isn't working properly, and the tasks always goes good, regardless the server is stopped or running.

Here is the code of my condition:

```
<condition property="check" value="true" >
<or>
<equals arg1="${state}" arg2="STOPPED" />
<equals arg1="${state}" arg2="STOPPING" />
</or>
</condition>
<fail if="${check}" message="Server stopped"/>
```

The variable state can have the next values: STOPPED, STOPPING or STARTED (I checked before that the value is correct). As I said, even if state = STOPPED or state = STOPPING, the property check is never set, so my task is always successful.

I have tried using forcestring and casesensitive in equals, and I have tried:

```
<fail if="check" message="Server stopped"/>
```

but the condition is still not working.

Any advice or idea on how to solve this and make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: `<fail if="check" message="Server stopped"/>` is definitely the correct way to use `<fail>`. What is the output if you put `<echo>check: ${check}</echo>` immediately before `<fail>`?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<fail message="Server stopped">
   <condition>
     <or>
       <equals arg1="${state}" arg2="STOPPED" />
       <equals arg1="${state}" arg2="STOPPING" />
     </or>
   </condition>
</fail>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
<target name="server_stopped" if="check">
        <fail message="Server stopped"/>
</target>
```